# Can't add DKMS configuration

Tags: software-installation

I found this command line in the forum and tried to followed it as it is mentioned it works…

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10
sudo depmod -a
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

But when I enter this command line I get this error

```
$ sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/.-rtl8192cu-fixes does not exist.
```

Please if anyone can sincerely help me. I am not really an advance user when it comes to Linux so your help and patience will be very helpful to me …

Comment: What is your question. All commands in your second command block work.

Comment: sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes < this one...  i get this error when i enter it Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/.-rtl8192cu-fixes does not exist.

Comment: Strange. Delete the cloned source folder `rm -r rtl8192cu-fixes` and clone the repository again: `git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git`

Comment: ~$ rm -r rtl8192cu-fixes
rm: cannot remove ‘rtl8192cu-fixes’: No such file or directory

Comment: what is the output of `git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git`

Comment: ~$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
dkms is already the newest version.
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.

Comment: !!! the output of `git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git`

Comment: The program 'git' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install git

Comment: Answer added. o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say in the comments:

> The program 'git' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install git

**Read the error messages before you continue.**

To clone a Git repository, you have to install `git`

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Now run the commands below in the **same** folder

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10
sudo depmod -a
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

Comment: i still get this error  :~$ sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/.-rtl8192cu-fixes does not exist.

Comment: What is the output of `git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git`

Comment: ~$ git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
Cloning into 'rtl8192cu-fixes'...
remote: Counting objects: 435, done.
remote: Total 435 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 435
Receiving objects: 100% (435/435), 1.79 MiB | 232.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (222/222), done.
Checking connectivity... done.

Comment: `ls -la rtl8192cu-fixes`

Comment: whats next sir? do i need to paste everything here?

Comment: Yes, the output of `ls -la rtl8192cu-fixes` add the output here http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and give me the link

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13395783/

Comment: In the **same** folder where you have started the `ls` command, run `sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes`

Comment: Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/8192cu/1.10/source ->
                 /usr/src/8192cu-1.10

DKMS: add completed. so now can i continue with the rest of the command?

Comment: Yes. Run all other commands.

Comment: wait sir one more question... because when doing this command line sudo depmod -a i only get this markmagus@markmagus-Aspire-E5-473:~$ sudo depmod -a
markmagus@markmagus-Aspire-E5-473:~$

Comment: Yes, why not? Not every program generates an output. And no output means in your case: All fine.

Comment: wow now it is working perfectly..really thank you for your help ...your awesome...

Answer (score 1):

A new reason for the same error might now be that the original git repository has changed, so the line

```
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10
```

needs to be changed into

```
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.11
```

For the problem of the original poster, the line

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
```

could also be extended to

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms git
```